# "Fake proof" of discrete Fourier transform of $x(n)$?

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-analysis

I originally thought about posting this in the Digital Signal Processing StackExchange, but I feel it's more adequate here. Basically, I want to rigorously justify a step which may or not be false - I don't know!

Let $x(n)$ be the indicator function for $0\leq n \leq N-1$ (in signal processing terms, $x(n)=u(n)-u(n-N)$). Then its discrete Fourier transform of length $N$ is given by

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-2\pi i \frac{n}{N}k}$$

for $0\leq k \leq N-1$. This looks a lot like a geometric series (if $k\neq 0$), hence I feel like I can claim

$$e^{-2\pi i \frac{n}{N}k} = ({e^{-2\pi i \frac{1}{N}k}})^{n}$$

and do the sum as usual. However, for complex exponents isn't this identity that I used false in general? For $k\neq 0$ it gives the correct result, zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine, since for real $x$ and integer $n$, we always have $e^{inx} = \left(e^{ix}\right)^{n}$. See [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula).

Comment: Huh, can't believe I didn't think about that. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! See the section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Failure_for_non-integer_powers,_and_generalization for some discussion on non-integer powers.